# windows mobile smsand contact access problem?

Tags: windows-mobile

i want to copy my sms and contact no.s from my Imate k-jam windows mobile by connecting it as a usb device how can i do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Microsoft Outlook to sync your contacts with your phone through USB.

Unfortunately, text messages are not stored in a easily-accessible location on Windows Mobile phones. There are programs that will let you [sync SMS messages](http://www.mobitnt.com/SMS-Outlook/SMS-SYNC-outlook.php) or [backup them up](http://www.spritesoftware.com/products/sprite-backup/full-edition).